# Disabling jqueryui on a form / remove style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

"Specs", I'm using

- jquery 1.8.0
- livequery
- jqueryUI 1.10.0 via google servers and tried via jquery servers also
- twitter bootstrap

I'm using jqueryui for my search suggestions which works well, I'm using a dark theme there black background and grayish text there. I also have an contact (email) form on the site. I've noticed that jquery-ui.js then also makes my contact form have light grey color. Since this contact form has white background-color (twitter bootstrap) this doesn't work, the text is hard to read! Both when typing and after naving to next field. the  is not affected.

How do I prevent jqueryui affecting a form (I assume this is possible / should be). It adds: `style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"` to the input fields.

It feels like a hack to override this style via my own javascript/jquery! Should this really be necessary. Also I tried this but it failed. I tried:

```
$('input').removeAttr('style');
```

Feels like they aren't going about styling forms in any good practice! Why aren't forms at least controlled by a class like `<form class="jquery-ui-form">` or something instead of f*ing up all forms.

Comment: try `$("input").attr("style", "");` or, you can try specifying your CSS and add `!important` to give it more priority. eg: `input { color: #000 !important; }`

Comment: input { color: #000 !important; } worked! Thanks! Still it feels like a hack to a poor implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important` only when you want to define a not overridable css rule in your website like :

`#input { color: #000 !important; }`

Which means : "no matter what, in my website, input will never have any other color than #000". This way, `!important` can be an option.

In any other case, ask yourself what is the scope of your css rule.

- Is it for only one input ? => use an `#id` to target your input or define style in js with `.css(...)`
- For all inputs in a specific tag ? => simply define a more specific rule to target your input like `.parent-div-class input { color: ... }`. The rule will have a better priority than `input { color: ... }` and will override property.

`!important` may be the easy way but is not the best.

Comment: I forgot that !important overrules inlines styles, I though it was the opposite that's why I didn't try it. However I'm as you very against using it.. it's last resort for me but seems to be the only thing working right now..